# Erro ao gerar relatório em produção - ReportViewer Versão 11

Tags: c#, webforms, reportviewer

Estou trabalhando com webforms e gerando um relatório no reportviewer localmente, o relatório aceita parâmetros e possui um dataset

```
// Parametros
List<ReportParameter> parametersReport = new List<ReportParameter>();
parametersReport.Add(new ReportParameter("Nome", "Nome Teste TI"));
parametersReport.Add(new ReportParameter("Idade", "25"));

// DataSet
RecursoDeGlosaDataSet recursoDataSet = new RecursoDeGlosaDataSet();

// recursosFinalizados **vem do banco
recursosFinalizados.ToList().ForEach(y =>
{
     recursoDataSet.Recurso.AddRecursoRow(
                y.DataInicioRealizacao.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                y.DataFim.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                y.CodigoTabela,
                y.CodigoProcedimento,
                y.DescricaoProcedimento,
                y.GrauParticipacao,
                y.CodigoItem,
                y.ValorRecursado.ToString(),
                y.Justificativaitem,
                y.ValorAcatado.ToString(),
                y.JustificativaCliente);
});

ReportViewer ReportViewer = new ReportViewer();

ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
eportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "caminhoDoRelatorio"; // o caminho está ok

ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(
new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("RecursoDeGlosaDataSet",
(System.Data.DataTable)recursoDataSet.RecursoGlosa));

ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parametersReport);

string mimeType = "";
string encoding = "";
string filenameExtension = "";
string[] streams = null;
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[] warnings = null;
string theDeviceSettings = "<DeviceInfo> 
<HumanReadablePDF>True</HumanReadablePDF></DeviceInfo>";

byte[] bytes = ReportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", theDeviceSettings, 
out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streams, out 
warnings);
```

Agora vou ao erro: relatório roda perfeitamente em minha máquina mas ao colocar em PRODUÇÂO caiu no seguinte erro :

```
Ocorreu um erro durante o processamento de relatórios local.     
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()     at 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 
parameters)
```

*Obs: instalei o reportviewer pelo nuget, então as seguintes dlls estão em produção (Install-Package Microsoft.Report.Viewer -Version 11.0.0)

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algumas DLL's são requeridas no servidor para o funcionamento do Report Viewer, ao fazer deploy além das DLL's que você já incluiu tente adicionar as seguintes:

1. Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll
2. Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll

Comment: Incrível cara, salvou meu dia vlw msm !!!